# C++ array and method

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to explain this

```
void m(int, int[]);

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y[10];
    y[0] = 1;

    m (x, y)
    cout >> x >> endl;
    cout >> y >> endl;

    return 0;
}

void m (int num, int nums[])
{
    num = 100;
    nums[0] = 1000;
}
```

The output of the x and y are

x is still 1, but y is replaced to 1000

I don't know why this is happened.

why integer array y[0] is replaced while integer x is still 1?

Comment: If you're going to learn C++ you're going to have to start using Standard Library containers like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) rather than C-style fixed-length arrays. Also you're passing by value, so changes are local in scope.

Comment: What book are you learning C++ from that doesn't explain this?

Comment: `m (x, y) cout` is a syntax error. Please check you have posted the exact code you are compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets take a look:

```
void m (int num, int nums[])
{
    num = 100;
    nums[0] = 1000;
}
```

(The following explanation is simplified.)
You can see that `num` is a simple parameter and therefore its `value` is given to the function which is actually a copy of the original variable. This is called call-by-value. Whatever you do with the variable in your function, it will only modify the local copy but not the variable in the original variable.

The `nums` variable tho is used as reference. (Note that in function signatures the term `int nums[]` is equivalient to `int* nums`.) You are not giving the value (a copy) to the function but a reference in form of a pointer. That is why this is called call-by-reference. If you modify this variable, the original value is modified (because you passed only the pointer (actually it isnot a reference)).

To get more information, i suggest you take a look into some C++ book because this is a very basic concept which you have to understand if you want to continue programming (with C++). A starting point for example would be [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Comment: "You are not giving the value (a copy) to the function but a reference" Actually, a pointer, In C++ pointers and references are two very different things. And cplusplus.com is not a great site to recommend.

Comment: Thank you. I'm completely new at C++, so I probably miss this important point :D

Comment: @NeilButterworth: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. Of course, I didn't mean a reference, but i wanted to use the term for the later use of the naming "call-by-reference". I edited my answer.